# XSLT Transform Relocating xmlns Instance

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<root xmlns:myns="derf">
    <child>
        <grandchild>mikey</grandchild>
    </child>
</root>
```

And I'm trying to turn it into the following XML:

```
<root xmlns="theNamespace" xmlns:myns="derf">
    <child>
        <grandchild>mikey</grandchild>
    </child>
</root>
```

I thought the following XSLT would do it:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/root"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <root xmlns="theNamespace">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Though that emits:

```
<root xmlns="theNamespace">
    <child xmlns="" xmlns:myns="derf">
        <grandchild>mikey</grandchild>
    </child>
</root>
```

Can someone help me understand - and ideally fix - why that `xmlns:myns="derf"` ends up on the `child` node instead of the `root` node in my output?

I'm basically just looking to augment the original XML with the `xmlns` namespace value.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here - first, you are only putting the `root` element in the `theNamespace` namespace, so the child elements are still in their original (null) namespace. Secondly, the `<xsl:copy>` does the job of copying an element's namespaces, but a literal element will not. This XSLT should behave the way you are describing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[name() = local-name()]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="theNamespace">
      <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[name() != '']" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<root xmlns="theNamespace" xmlns:myns="derf">
  <child>
    <grandchild>mikey</grandchild>
  </child>
</root>
```